# Problema con Login a Web de Facebook en PHP

Tags: facebook, facebook-api

Estoy utilizando la SDK de Facebook y al intentar realizar la autenticación me devuelve el siguiente error, en cuanto a la configuración de la Aplicación creo que esta todo ok porque funcionó hasta ahora sin problema, hace unos dias que comenzó esto, no se si Facebook abra cambiado algo en su plataforma, busque por Google y muchos dicen que la solución es desactivar la opcion "*Usar modo estricto para URI de redireccionamiento*" el problema es que ahora no lo permite ya que la misma aparece como inhabilitada y no se puede cambiar.

**MENSAJE DE ERROR:**

> No se puede cargar la URL: El dominio de esta URL no está incluido en los dominios de la aplicación. Para poder cargar esta URL, agrega
>   todos los dominios y subdominios de tu aplicación en el campo
>   "Dominios de la aplicación" en la configuración de la aplicación.

Adjunto una imagen del error que me da.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero puedan ayudarme, desde ya gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Hacia finales del mes pasado Facebook realizó cambios en la plataforma de desarrolladores, habilitando para todos la opción "Use Strict Mode for Redirect URIs" entre otras cosas. Te recomiendo lo siguiente:

1. Verificar el listado de la URIs validas para redireccionar
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
2. En caso de que el error persista, colocar en el código la URI de redirección al momento de obtener el token. Con este ajuste me funcionó.
   Cambiar:

   ```
   $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
   ```

   por

   ```
   $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken('redirect_url');
   ```

Answer (score 1):

**Solución en mi caso. Al error de**:

> “El dominio de esta URL no está incluido en los dominios de la
>   aplicación”.

Configure la aplicación correctamente:

1. **Configuración Básica** - Dominios de la aplicación ingrese el dominio de dos maneras midominio.com y www.midominio.com
2. **Productos – Inicio de sesión con Facebook** - URI de
       redireccionamiento de OAuth válidos  ingrese:
       “https://midominio.com/includes/redes_sociales/hydridauth.php?hauth_done=Facebook&scope=email”

De todos modos seguía sin funcionar.
**La solución fue eliminar la aplicación y volver a crearla**.

**Uso**:
Api de facebook v3.0 (En la página no me permite bajar la versión)
Facebook php sdk 5.4
hybridOuth v3.0.0 RC 6

Conclusión: Cree la aplicación antes del 1 de marzo de 2018, trabaje siempre en modo desarrollo durante este periodo. El inicio de sesión funcionaba bien de manera local. Pero al subirlo al servidor y poner la aplicación en modo producción, daba el error “El dominio de esta URL no está incluido en los dominios de la aplicación”. 
Es probable que debido a las recientes actualizaciones de facebook, se aya producido algún conflicto, que se soluciona al borrar la aplicación y volver a crearla.

Espero que a alguien le ayude, porque a mi me tuvo varios días dando vueltas este problema.